# Нужно определить принадлежат ли точки окружности

Tags: python, функции, математика

Даны координаты точки i = [0, 1]
Радиус круга r = 3

я написал функцию

```
def get_result(i, r):
    return (i[0]** 2 and i[1]** 2 < r** 2)
```

ожидаемое значение теста должно быть - True (точки принадлежат кругу)
но фактическое значение выдает -  0
видимо у меня совсем хромает математика, и я не вижу очевидных вещей?
Помогите разобраться пожалуйста

Comment: Принадлежат *окружности* или *кругу*? Это две очень большие разницы!! Молчу уж, что в любом случае ваша функция неверна — ни с точки зрения геометрии, ни с точки зрения синтаксиса...

Comment: Ошибка в том что and не использован правильно. Проверьте, что точно ли 0**2 будет 1?

Comment: ошибся - Радиус круга r =3

Comment: в данном случае у вас проверяется, что первое число в квадрате не равно нулю и второй число в квадрате меньше радиуса в квадрате.

Comment: Разобрался, благодарю, квадраты тут вообще зря намудрил....